# Getting different results using Select by Location with ArcPy vs ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.2, select-by-location

I have two different layers. One layer contains features that are supposed to sit directly on top of features in the other layer.

With ArcPy I'm doing a `SelectLayerByLocation` with `"ARE_IDENTICAL_TO"` and then a `"SWITCH_SELECTION"` in order to find which features from layer one aren't directly on top of layer two, and then updating the geometry accordingly.

However, ArcPy is giving me different (incorrect) results than using the `Select by Location` in ArcMap.

Granted the feature is only 0.01 ft away from the other, but it's still not identical.

[image]

When using ArcPy, the feature above with the **S** is selected, but when I use `Select by Location` in ArcMap it's not.

```
layer1_fl = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer1, layer1 + "_fl")
layer2_fl = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer2, layer2 + "_fl")

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(layer1_fl, "ARE_IDENTICAL_TO", layer2_fl)
```

Any idea why it's acting this way?

---

As suggested by @FelixIP

I added `arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(102726)` and all worked as expected.

Comment: XY resolution and tolerance in Environmental Settings?

Comment: @FelixIP Didn't think of that, but I just tried setting it and it's still selecting them when it shouldn't.

Comment: Is there any chance that you are using buffers (which use true curves in a file geodatabase) to make the selection with projection-on-the-fly in place?  If so, what you think is a circle making the selection may be squashed slightly.  I'm not overly strong on coordinate systems but I tracked this down once and was only able to overcome it by copying the buffer feature class out to a shapefile and back to force a vertexed polygon to be created in the file geodatabase.

Comment: @PolyGeo no, all the layers are in same coordinate system. In the image above, I'm simply selecting all the boxes with the S that are directly on top of the hard to see point below where all the lines converge. All features are simple point features.

Comment: @ian Do you mind to update your Q with line from script? I lately found something weird with select by location from script... Even current workspace can affect it. One of the reason I use shapefiles so often

Comment: @FelixIP I added some code, but it's really simple- create 2 feature layers and do a select by location.

Comment: This is from help: The Select By Location tools available in the Selection menu in ArcMap, ArcScene, and ArcGlobe evaluate spatial relationship in the coordinate system of that application's display (the current data frame). For the geoprocessing tool to match this behavior (and get identical results), set output coordinate system environment to Same as Display

Comment: @FelixIP That worked, and it was right in the documentation! Mine was set to `Same as Input` - I guess even though all layers and the data frame are using the same state plane coordinate system, it never gets set because essentially there's no input - kind of strange. If you answer the question, I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract from help: The Select By Location tools available in the Selection menu in ArcMap, ArcScene, and ArcGlobe evaluate spatial relationship in the coordinate system of that application's display (the current data frame). For the geoprocessing tool to match this behavior (**and get identical results**), set output coordinate system environment to Same as Display

Glad it works, although I am struggling to understand, why it is a must do thing, when both layers are in the same projection

Comment: It really is strange, and makes you wonder how many people are unknowingly getting incorrect results because if it.