# Select Layer By Location (Management) gives different result in ArcPy and ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, intersection, select-by-location

I have two line Shape files. When I use the `Select layer by location` tool to select two intersecting lines, it works fine and selects only lines which are actually intersecting.

But when I use this in Python Script by below code, it select extra lines which are not actually intersecting the Source layer line.

```py
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Split_Line","INTERSECT","Line")
```

Why this tool works different in Python script?

I am actually trying to make an offset of a given Shape line. For this I created a buffer in memory, converted it into lines, split at vertices and delete the intersecting Feature to original line.

```py
 #specifying buffer distance
    buffer_feaure = "in_memory" + "\\" + "buffer" # temporary feature
    line_lyr = "in_memory" + "\\" "line" # temporary feauture
    #Make buffer along line
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(InputLine, buffer_feaure, "20 Meters", "LEFT", "FLAT", "ALL")
    #Convert buffer to polyline
    arcpy.PolygonToLine_management(buffer_feaure, line_lyr)
    #Line Layer Split at vertices
    Splitline_lyr = "in_memory" + "\\" "Splitline" # temporary feauture
    arcpy.SplitLine_management(line_lyr,Splitline_lyr )
    # Selecting layer to intersecting to the line inpput
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Splitline_lyr,"INTERSECT",InputLine)
    # Deleting Selected Features
    if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(Splitline_lyr).getOutput(0)) > 0:
        arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(Splitline_lyr)
```

It runs until it split lines at vertices and give below output.

[image]

Comment: What else is in your script?  How can you tell that  extra lines are being selected?  Please present a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck.

Comment: Question edited and example with picture is added

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your output coordinate system (in geoprocessing environment settings) to "Same As Display". This question was answered and discussed in more detail here:

[Getting different results using Select by Location with ArcPy vs ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172238/getting-different-results-using-select-by-location-with-arcpy-vs-arcmap)