# Selecting features from another shapefile using ArcPy cursors and SelectLayerByLocation?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, select-by-location

Having the code below im trying to select all the table features from an `school_enroll.shp` that are within each bigger zones from the `hs_bndy.shp`when i use the `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management` for some reason the selection isn't happening. Am i doing something wrong here? I like to be able to sum some of the fields from the selected `school_enroll.shp`  features

```
#hs
fields = {i:str(field.baseName) for i,field in enumerate(input)}
input = arcpy.ListFields("HS_Bndy1516.shp")
school_ampa = "C:/school_enroll.shp"
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("HS_Bndy1516.shp")

for row in rows:
    total = 0
    row_name =  row.getValue("NAME")
    sql = "{} = '{}'".format(fields[3], row_name)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("HS_Bndy1516.shp", 'school_lyr', sql)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('school_lyr',"HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN",school_ampa)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('school_lyr',"HSadd")as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            total = row[0] + total
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using arcpy? You could do this using the tools in ArcMap and then do a summarize tool to get the sums

Comment: i have over 200 districts and i'd thought i could do it this way. If i can get the selection done, i think i can automate the whole process.

Comment: Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172238/getting-different-results-using-select-by-location-with-arcpy-vs-arcmap/172242#172242

Comment: I believe you can use a spatial join http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/about-joining-the-attributes-of-features-by-their-location.htm