# Fast AOI polygon query for matching mosaic dataset footprints

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, performance, spatial-query, mosaic-dataset

Is there any more efficient/faster way to query a mosaic dataset raster catalog (footprints) for records matching an AOI polygon?

This implementation gets slower the larger the AOI polygon is.

```
import arcpy
import timeit

fgdb_path = 'H:/MY/FGDB/Rasters.gdb'
md_name = 'CIB1'
md_path = fgdb_path + '/' + md_name
md_cat_path = fgdb_path + '/AMD_' + md_name + '_CAT'
aoi_fc = 'H:/MY/FGDB.gdb/AOI'
out_paths = r'in_memory\paths'

# Get AOI poly from FC
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(aoi_fc,'SHAPE@') as sCur:
     for row in sCur:
         aoi_poly = row[0]

start_time = timeit.default_timer()

# Create OID list of MD raster footprints that the AOI overlaps/contains
oid_list = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(md_path,['SHAPE@', 'OID@']) as sCur:
     for row in sCur:
         if aoi_poly.overlaps(row[0]) or aoi_poly.contains(row[0]):
             oid_list.append(row[1])

elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print("Completed in " + str(elapsed))
```

System Info:

- ArcPy w/ Pro 2.8 python3
- ArcPy w/ ArcGIS Server 10.9 python3

Metrics:

- Mosaic Dataset Footprint: 280K
- Footprint size: 1SqMi
- Small AOI footprint match: 10K results, 30s completion
- Large AOI footprint match: 230K results, 230s completion

Comment: I think simple intersect of 2 polygons will be much-much faster.

Comment: Are you using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro or with ArcMap?  What time are you currently seeing printed out?

Comment: @PolyGeo I added sys info and metrics

Comment: @FelixIP thanks I'm testing `arcpy.analysis.Intersect` and `arcpy.Intersect_analysis` now, are these what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes. Intersect (fid only) to in_memory dataset. Get unique fids.

Comment: Perhaps 2 select layer by location , new selection, followed by add to selection? Anything but using geometry methods. They are slow like he'll.

Comment: @FelixIP `arcpy.analysis.Intersect` is a lot faster 234,858 returned in 9s BUT it's not accepting the MD - `arcpy.Intersect_analysis( ['C:/A.gdb/MD', 'C:/B.gdb/AOI'], r'in_memory\fids', 'ONLY_FID' )` , errors with `ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset C:/A.gdb/MD does not exist or is not supported`. A regular feature class works though... I tried `MD` and `AMD_MD_CAT`

Comment: Self-answer, please. Wonder why different spelling of same tool don't produce same result. Some sort of server games?

Comment: @FelixIP I tried both actually, same error. It appears I need to get the MD footprints into a feature class type format that intersect will support to be able to gain that speed increase... Looking into how to do that quickly...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129222/discussion-between-felixip-and-andy-arismendi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried on a Mosaic Dataset stored on an external hard-drive (40k rasters). This seems fastest:

[image]

Followed by:

```
aSet = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(r"NORTHLAND_MosaicLayer\Footprint","OID@"))
```

Note my AOI layer made up from 2945 polygons made of 1779853 (1.8M!) points.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! `MakeMosaicLayer_management` w/  `SelectLayerByLocation_management` is returning 200K+ AOI matches in under 10s :-) I noticed a few strange things though... `SelectLayerByLocation_management` does not appear to filter the footprint layer in specific python instances: AGS & ArcGIS Pro's arcgispro-py3. It works fine with AGS Python27 though... Not sure if this is a bug or not... Also `Intersect_analysis` w/ `ONLY_FID` returned the right amount of IDs but they didn't match the OIDs in from the source.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172238/getting-different-results-using-select-by-location-with-arcpy-vs-arcmap/172242#172242

Comment: `SelectLayerByLocation_management` not working on a VM using ArcGIS Server 10.9/ArcGIS Pro 2.8 arcgispro-py3 turned out to be a bug: `BUG-000143287`